# Correct REST call for creating a resource

Tags: rest

So i have a rest api, which has the following REST uri for creating a resource

/object/{id}

Im using an id that i pass in to set for the resource, in mongo there is also an objectId which is different.

```
json:

object: {
  "id":id
  .....
  .....
}

mongo:

 object: {
  "objectId"....
  "id":....

}
```

my question is, is this correct usage of the POST in REST. I could remove the id fromt he uri... and do a POST to ../object with the id in the body.

I thought this was correct since mongo would create an ID, the only doubt i have is that i then use this id that i have passed in for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the ID in the URI if you are creating a new resource because route parameters are generally used to locate pre-existing resources. For example:

```
/countries/{countryName}/capital-city
/albums/{albumId}/release-date
/books/{bookId}/author
```

Just remember that your API endpoint should just describe the location of where the operation will take place, and the HTTP method should just roughly document the type of operation that will take place.

So if you want to add (POST) a new item to a table called "Objects", then your endpoint name should reflect that:

```
POST {your-webapp-name}/Objects
```

Comment: Yes i understand that. But I also include an Id in the post, which i then use to identify the object and perform PUT, GET. which doesnt sit well with me, but i need somethin descriptive for the end user to sue to identify this object rather than a uuid...

Comment: What other properties do you have in "Object"? REST doesn't care about what you use to identify a resource, so you could use anything from a string name to a uuid. Primary key look ups are good because they're generally faster.

Comment: my ibject has.. id, name. value... the id is what i set when i create the resource and it is what i use to lookup ie GET, PUT. I just thought it was against REST to lookup on an object with an ID that we specify on creation.

Comment: Not at all, there's nothing wrong with doing that. Using ID to create a resource and then using that same ID for lookups seems totally logical to me. Using a real world example of that - you can create your own personalise car registration plate (the same as an ID), and then use that same registration plate you've just created to perform lookups on your car.